Is it acceptable to bring a holiday ham to Colombia?
I am planning to cook for the new years in Colombia and I wanted to make a holiday ham but in Colombia doesn’t have that in the country so I wanted to know will it be acceptable to bring it and how many will it be acceptable?

On TripAdvisor last year, it might depend on what kind of ham you want.

Sorry for perhaps being ignorant, but if you are planning to cook yourself, why not just buy pork meat in Colombia and prepare a holiday ham from that? It is probably no problem at all to get pork meat there. What is the 'that' you are referring to, which they don't have in Colombia?

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo "a holiday ham" has most likely been cured, a somewhat involved process which takes weeks to complete properly. It's not just as simple as cooking a piece of meat.

A quick search suggests you can buy Spanish-style hams in Colombia such as https://laiberica.co/collections/jamones-enteros-con-hueso and something closer to American-style hams such as https://www.tiendalafazenda.com/jamon-pierna-fazenda


will it be acceptable to bring it and how many will it be acceptable?

None.
Meat and animal based foodstuffs are banned from entry

However, it was reported here "The Colombian Agriculture and Stockbreeding Institute (ICA) informed that the passengers of international flights that arrive in Colombia will be able to bring in shoulders and hams (cooked or cured bone-in) from Spain."

@WeatherVane: That's from a decade ago. I don't think it still applies.
